# MVVM : RaisePropertyChange on another item in the same list

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am using MVVM Light in a (pretty simple) WPF project.

I have a list of versions, and for each of them there is a button "activate" and "archive". Only one version can be active.
When clicking on "activate", the software must archive the currently active version, and activate the selected one.
How would you modelize this ? I'm currently using a pretty ugly solution : the selected version re-instantiates the "active version" and archives it, so obviously the previously-active version isn't "refreshed".

The main window contains a list of versions, displayed in a ListBox (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24202166/style-list-item-based-on-its-property/24202335#24202335)).

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        this.InstalledVersions = InstalledVersionViewModel.GetInstalledVersions();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<InstalledVersionViewModel> InstalledVersions { get; set; }
}
```

The InstalledVersionViewModel is (simplified) like this :

```
public class InstalledVersionViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public InstalledVersionViewModel()
    {
        this.HandleActivateVersionCommand = new RelayCommand<RoutedEventArgs>(e => { this.ActivateVersion(); });
        this.HandleArchiveVersionCommand = new RelayCommand<RoutedEventArgs>(e => { this.ArchiveVersion(); });
    }

    public string FolderPath { get; set; }

    public RelayCommand<RoutedEventArgs> HandleActivateVersionCommand { get; private set; }

    public RelayCommand<RoutedEventArgs> HandleArchiveVersionCommand { get; private set; }

    public string VersionNumber { get; set; }

    public static InstalledVersionViewModel GetCurrentVersion()
    {
        return GetVersionInfos(baseInstallPath); // returns the currently-active version
    }

    public static ObservableCollection<InstalledVersionViewModel> GetInstalledVersions()
    {
        var list = new ObservableCollection<InstalledVersionViewModel>();
        // snip : fill the list from detected versions
        return list;
    }

    private void ActivateVersion()
    {
        // snip
        GetCurrentVersion().Archive();
        // snip
    }

    private void ArchiveVersion()
    {
        // snip
    }
}
```

The problem is in the ActivateVersion() method : I'm getting a new version instance to archive it, so obviously the version instance in the list is never aware of this change. But I don't know how to change the behavior to archive the version in the list instead. I'm pretty sure there should be either some kind of messaging system, a wrapper or an overarching structure, but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it should be handled in the `MainViewModel`. For instance, add a property `IsActive` to your `InstalledVersionViewModel`, and subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event from your `MainViewModel`. When the event is raised, browse your `InstalledVersions` list to find the previously active item, and call the `Archive` method on it.

---

To subscribe to the event, simply browse your list after creating it:

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    this.InstalledVersions = InstalledVersionViewModel.GetInstalledVersions();

    foreach (var version in this.InstalledVersions)
    {
        version.PropertyChanged += this.VersionPropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Then, in the event, check which property has been changed:

```
private void VersionPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "IsActive")
    {
        var changedVersion = (Version)sender;

        // Checks that the version has been activated
        if (changedVersion.IsActive)
        {
            // Finds the previously active version and archive it
            foreach (var version in this.InstalledVersions)
            {
                if (version.IsActive && version != changedVersion)
                {
                    version.Archive();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was starting to think that would be the general architecture (even though I was going for regular events but that's not very MVVM-y), but how do you "subscribe to the propertychanged event", especially of the items in a list ? Thanks !